# Find a src image value from an <a href> tag

Tags: javascript, href, src, image-gallery, imagesource

I've been building an image gallery with pictures in the hundreds and I don't want them all to load on page load for obvious bandwidth issues. For starters, I put;

```
<body onload="removeAttr("src")">
```

to prevent the pictures from loading which works... too well I'm afraid as it doesn't load my website header banner pic.  Anyhow, my gallery is set up with a menu with each button representing a different image. The menu is displayed in this format;

```
 <ul id="menu">
     <li><a href="#pic1">Title</a></li>
 </ul>
```

with many buttons. When that button is clicked it loads the graphic linked with it into a div called "gallery" All the images are loaded into the "gallery" with overflow: hidden which is why they want to load initially, that code appears as;

```
 <div id="gallery">
    <div>
       <a name="pic1"></a><img alt="" src="../images/characters/character1.jpg" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Again with many images in it. My script listens for a mouse click and immediately grabs the
a href value associated with it, so "pic1", then it uses that to find the image name linked with it so "character1.jpg" and stores it in a variable. (Which I firmly believe is where my problem lies). It then, targeting the "gallery" div deletes any picture previously in there then inserts the new image (the one stored in a variable). All this is in an attempt to load only the graphic the user wants to see not all of them.  That alert displays the button number so that part works, and I know it deletes the image loaded in the div as it seems to be loading the first image in the list which then vanishes upon testing, but then it never replaces it with a new one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onclick = function(e) {
  var node = e.target;
  while (node != undefined && node.localName != 'a') {
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  if (node != undefined) {

    if (this.id == 'alternate-image') {
      var Imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      alert(src);
    }

    var dv = document.getElementById('gallery');
    // remove all child nodes
    while (dv.hasChildNodes()) {
      dv.removeChild(dv.lastChild);
    }
    alert("The button value is:  " + node);

    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = Imgsrc;
    dv.appendChild(img);

    return false; // stop handling the click
  } else {
    alert('This is not a link: ' + e.target.innerHTML)
    return true; // handle other clicks
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you enhancing your programming skills or trying to realize a project? See [here](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/) for a photo gallery example project.

Comment: how about trying with     **var Imgsrc= $(this).find('img')[0].attr('src');**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your issue, but I do see an issue with your code.

You are defining `var Imgsrc` within an `if` block. If the expression is not true, then `Imgsrc` will not be defined. Yet later in your code you use it, regardless of conditions, without checking if it's defined in the first place.

See my code comments below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onclick = function(e) {
  var node = e.target;
  while (node != undefined && node.localName != 'a') {
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  if (node != undefined) {

    if (this.id == 'alternate-image') {
      var Imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src'); //<!---- here you define the Imgsrc var 
      //but what if the this.id != 'alternate-image'??
      alert(src);
    }

    var dv = document.getElementById('gallery');
    // remove all child nodes
    while (dv.hasChildNodes()) {
      dv.removeChild(dv.lastChild);
    }
    alert("The button value is:  " + node);

    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = Imgsrc; //<!---- need to check if this is defined.
    dv.appendChild(img);

    return false; // stop handling the click
  } else {
    alert('This is not a link: ' + e.target.innerHTML)
    return true; // handle other clicks
  }
}
</script>
```

Any chance you can post your html or more detail so we can resolve this?

Comment: I must thank you, After your isolating that if statement issue, (which I removed the 'if' statement and left; ` var Imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src'); alert(src);` as a declaration, it is loading the images fine so, though my code isn't as elegant as the other posters' here, at least it works, I can't thank you enough. Sometimes fresh eyes make all the difference!

Comment: One final thing, because, by the sounds of things, I'll be using my original code with Jan's improvement, there is one final thorn. Is it possible to make exceptions with the `<body onload="removeAttr("src")">' because it also prevents my website's header image from loading?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the full source on a GitHub gist or a pastebin?

Here's a simpler way to do it. You don't need to add and remove new image elements, just change the `src` attribute on an existing one.

```
<ul class='imageMenu'>
  <li data-image="dog.jpg">dog</li>
  <li data-image="cat.jpg">cat</li>
  <li data-image="donkey.jpg">donkey</li>
</ul>
<img src="" id='selectedImage' />
<script>
  const img = document.querySelector('#selectedImage');
  document.querySelectorAll('.imageMenu li').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      img.setAttribute('src', evt.target.getAttribute('data-image'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you Ryan for replying so quick, I must apologize, I've only been slow to respond as I'm trying to make sense of the code (which gives you an idea of my limitations). From my limited knowledge it looks like you are taking the list values and applying a listener (for the button click I assume) on the whole list and when one is clicked insert the dog.jpg value say into that image src called 'selected Image' am I right? Sorry, I'm trying to learn. If this is so, do I then use the id 'selected Image' as the variable in the script I made when inserting it into the gallery div?

Comment: ...wait it is the only image which always stays loaded in the gallery! I think I'm getting it! Oh boy you may all have a laugh at my expense... feel free.

Comment: Haha, no worries. The idea is that there's only one image element on the page, which we save as `img`; instead of adding and removing images to change them, you just take `img` and change the URL it refers to, which causes it to reload with its new URL. `querySelectorAll` is getting a list of all the `li` elements, and adding a separate listener to each one of them. When any `li` is clicked, it takes its `data-image` attribute, and changes `img`'s `src` to point to that. So all you have to do is make sure that each `data-image` has the filename that should load.

Comment: One thing to note, looking at your original example, is that you don't need to have one click listener for the entire window, and then try to figure out which element within it was clicked.  You can add a listener to just an individual item, or to each of a list of items, which is simpler. In my example above, `evt.target` always refers to whichever `li` item the user clicked on.

Comment: Just one more thing... hopefully. I'm just testing the code @Ryan posted and I've inserted the script below the `if (node != undefined) {` command (which can be referenced in my initial post) hopefully that's right anyways, there seems to be a syntax error centered around the `.forEach(item => {` section of code. I've been trying to debug but since I don't  quite understand it is difficult. Don't mistake me, I'm not criticizing rather I'm praising his code it is absolutely brilliant, I can't wait to see it in action!I think I'm getting it otherwise.

Comment: wait, if that's the only image on the page do I still need to prevent the pictures from loading onload? Is the entire picture database still loaded with the page or does the code kick out one in favour of the next?

Comment: You don't need to prevent the pictures from loading onload anymore. By default, none will be loaded; each time the user clicks a list item, the corresponding image will load, and that image alone.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a revised set of markup and code.  Since you appear to have jQuery in your code, I will use that.

Menu of images:

```
<ul id="menu">
     <li class="image-link" data-image="../images/characters/character1.jpg">Title 1</li>
     <li class="image-link" data-image="../images/characters/character2.jpg">Title 2</li>
     <li class="image-link" data-image="../images/characters/character3.jpg">Title 3</li>
</ul>
```

One place to show them:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img alt="" src="" />
</div>
```

Code to show them:

```
$('#menu').on('click','.image-link',function(){
   $('#gallery').find('img').attr('src', $(this).data('image'));
});
```

Comment: Both ideas seem great though I can't seem to get either to work. I've uploaded a couple versions on megashare so you can see the code. If you wan't to see the intended effect visit http://www.theamityblade.com/Characters.html. This version access the images through a css; http://megashare.megahd.com.br/2Wc. I've had to abort it as it doesn't work in IE and isn't exactly elegant. Anyhow, Mark's proposed solution is this version; http://megashare.megahd.com.br/2Wa and Ryan's is; http://megashare.megahd.com.br/2Wb I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your linked HTML has some challenges - multiple jQuery versions linked in there, you should really use a more recent copy.  I created a fiddle here that logs the image selected - no image appears as I have none BUT you can see the actual working code wrapped in a document ready closure https://jsfiddle.net/jvtmf794/

Comment: For what it is worth, I did a test to prefix the referenced site to the image reference text and it does show the image when you click one.  I won't post that code as it would reference the site and I would not want to do that without permission i.e. link to images.