# change image src in internet explorer via javascript

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, gallery, src

following up on my previous post:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722251/find-a-src-image-value-from-an-a-href-tag)

I wanted to post this in it's own topic so others can find it easier and if it's a duplicate I apologize. In my previous post a fellow named Ryan offered a solution to my problem which, at the time didn't work, though I was tired, it was late, and perhaps I was missing something. Anyhow, he suggested that I change the image src with every button pressed instead of having all images load initially which, admittingly is a far more elegant solution. He offered this code;

```
<ul class='imageMenu'>
  <li data-image="dog.jpg">dog</li>
  <li data-image="cat.jpg">cat</li>
  <li data-image="donkey.jpg">donkey</li>
</ul>
<img src="" id='selectedImage' />
<script>
  const img = document.querySelector('#selectedImage');
  document.querySelectorAll('.imageMenu li').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      img.setAttribute('src', evt.target.getAttribute('data-image'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now with time and refreshed with sleep I got it working except in internet explorer. My question is, is there some code to add for internet explorer like an if statement to say "if in internet explorer run this code instead."? Again I'm sorry if I'm redundant I'm just lost, and for the record, Internet Explorer is the bane of my existence it is the whole reason I've had to re code the page to begin with. Anyways, any advice where to turn would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Black_Lightning

Comment: What version of IE are you talking about? And what error do you get in IE?

Comment: I use IE 8 (8.0.7601.17514).  I never saw any errors in the console.

Comment: Well, there you go. IE 8 is not widely used anymore, but is woefully not compliant with standards. Just curious, why are you still on IE8? See my updated answer below.

Comment: Every time I do windows update my computer breaks so I vowed to never update again, I swear Microsoft is more deadly than any virus I've ever met at least with those I obliterate the drive and then do an Acronis recovery and all is fine. Not to mention, if I'm on IE8, others may be too so it gives me a good baseline, if it works on my machine it will on others' too and I want to reach the widest audience I can. I just don't know why my sloppy JavaScript I posted in my previous thread works and not the more elegant solutions. I'd gladly use mine too if I could get my head picture to load.

Comment: According to **[MarketShare.com](https://www.netmarketshare.com/report.aspx?qprid=3&qpaf=&qpcustom=Microsoft+Internet+Explorer+8.0&qpcustomb=0)**, IE 8 is used by less than 1% of web users. It is the last version of IE before MS made any sort of commitment to any web standards. As a result, it is just about universally not considered when thinking about developing for compatibility. In fact, most sites only consider being compatible with IE 10 or up. There are proprietary "in-house" apps that may still require it, but for the public, we no longer write code to be compatible with it.

Answer (score 1):

First `const` and arrow functions are ECMAScript 6 features that are not  supported in IE 8 so you should use `var` and no arrow functions instead.

Next, `.forEach()` and `.querySelectorAll()` are not supported in IE 8 either.

But, the most important one is that IE 8 doesn't support `.addEventListener()` as a way to bind callback functions to events, it uses the proprietary **[`attachEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/attachEvent)**.

Now, we don't want to check for IE per se, we just need to know if the features we want to use are available and that is called **["feature detection"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273397(v=vs.85).aspx)**.

You should definitely be aware of **http://caniuse.com** as a good resource to check to see what is supported where.

See this cross-browser version below:

```js
// IE 8 doesn't support .forEach, .querySelectorAll or .addEventListener

var img = document.getElementById('selectedImage');
var menu = document.getElementById('imageMenu');

for(var i = 0; i < menu.childNodes.length; i++){
  
  // We're looping through all the child nodes, but we only care about <li> elements:
  if(menu.childNodes[i].nodeName === "LI"){

    // Check to see if addEventListener is supported
    if(window.addEventListener){
      // Modern, standards-compliant browser
      menu.childNodes[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        img.setAttribute('src', evt.target.getAttribute("data-image"));
        // Test
        console.log(img.src);
      });
    } else {
      // IE 8 or less
      menu.childNodes[i].attachEvent("onclick", function(evt){
        evt = evt || window.event;
        img.setAttribute('src', evt.srcElement.getAttribute("data-image"));
        // Test
        console.log(img.src);        
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id='imageMenu'>
  <li data-image="dog.jpg">dog</li>
  <li data-image="cat.jpg">cat</li>
  <li data-image="donkey.jpg">donkey</li>
</ul>
<img src="" id='selectedImage' />
```

Here is the code running on IE 11 in IE 8 emulation mode and, you can see it is producing the correct results.

[image: Code running in IE 8 emulation mode]

Comment: Thanks. Like with Ryan's code it seems to work in all but IE, the error it gave was a syntax error pointing to this line; liArray.forEach(item => {  and that was with me hoping/praying it would work. I will continue to try to get it to work, so if I don't immediately reply that's why.

Comment: I ran your new snippet and it gave an error "object required" for character 16 (my calculations brings it to the i following the semi colon: `for(var i = 0; i < menu.childNodes.length; i++){` I'm really loathing ie about now! Grrr!

Comment: I have tested the code in IE running in IE 8 emulation mode and it works correctly (see picture above). If it's not working for you, you must not have placed the script code just before the closing of the `body` tag or made some other error in setting the code up.

Answer (score 1):

I have found something simple that works! It is only a few lines of easy to understand code! Thanks again to all here and on my previous post which have offered their assistance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function change_pic(p) {
  document.images._pimg.src = p;
  // alert('test');
}
</script>

<img name="_pimg" src="image.jpg" >

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_pic('image.jpg')">image</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_pic('image2.jpg')">image 2</a>
```

Comment: The `name` attribute is invalid on non-form elements. It should be `id` and, if you change it then the line can just be: `_pimg.src = p`;

Comment: While this code is simple and does "work". It's non-standard and doesn't follow modern coding standards and best-practices.